# verilog IEEE 754 single precision to integer conversion

Tags: integer, verilog, ieee-754

I am trying to convert a [IEEE single precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision_floating-point_format) binary format number to an integer. I am using the following loop:

```
for(i=22;i>=0;i=i-1)
begin
   a1=in1[i]*(2**(i-23));
end
a1=a1+1;
a1=a1*(2**(in1[30:23]-8'b01111111));
a1=((-1)**(in1[32]))*a1;
```

I need to do this 7 more times in my program. My question is if there is a library to do this, that takes a 32 bit input and gives an integer output? If yes how do I include that function in my program?
Thank you.

update: will the snippet above work correctly?

Comment: There is a floating point core on opencores. Do you have a synthesis target, or is this for simulation only? What is your output format? In a comment below you say you want it "exactly the same" which would require a fixed point format using hundreds of bits.

Comment: this is for simulation only. I am trying to write code for floating point unit of SPU of Cell processor. Depending on the instruction I have to do different tasks on floating point numbers. The numbers are represented by 32 bits. I want to add, subtract ... them and store them in another 32 bit field. In the snippet above, I converted in1 to a1. I have to convert in2 to a2 similarly and do a1+a2 or a1-a2 or... and store it in c2. Then, I should be able to convert it back to out1 which is 32 bits wide. I hope you get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it would be to:

1. re-pack the operands in 64-bit double precision format
2. convert the values to reals with `$bitstoreal`
3. use native verilog floating point math to operate on the reals
4. convert the reals back to bits with `$realtobits`
5. convert the 64-bit double back to single-precision format. The value needs to be clipped if it is outside the representable range (there are both "too far from zero" and "too close to zero" cases that need to be clamped).

If you want to convert the floats to fixed point using the strategy in the question, keep in mind that Verilog does not have native fixed point support. You cannot meaningfully evaluate 2^(negative exponent) as an integer, you'll just get zero. Either restructure the algorithm so the exponents are always positive, or use right-shifts (`>>`) rather than multiplication by a negative power of two.

Answer (score 2):

For behavioral code use either $rtoi() or $realtobits()

```
real in1;
integer     a1;
wire [63:0] b1;
a1 = $roti(in1); //Truncates fractional part
b1 = $realtobits(in1); //Probably not what you want
```

You can use $bitstoreal() if you need to cast a bit vector to a real type.

EDIT:
So if I follow your comments correctly, you're building a model of a floating-point ALU that works on 32-bit data values. In this case you could use *real* data types since Verilog can handle this format natively. Of course, you won't be able to detect certain situations

```
task [31:0] realAdd(input [31:0] in1, input [31:0] in2, output [31:0] out);
begin

real rIn1,rIn2,rOut;
rIn1 = $bitstoreal(in1);
rIn2 = $bitstoreal(in2);
rOut = rIn1 + rIn2;

out = $realtobits(rOut);

end
endtask
```

These functions all use double precision so you'll need to do some trivial bit extensions to handle single precision inputs, and some non-trivial bounds checking/truncation on the output. You can avoid this by using SystemVerilog, which has the $bitstoshortreal()/$shortrealtobits() functions that work on single precision values.

If you want hardware for this, [Computer Organization & Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558604286) has a description of a multi cycle implementation. As Andy posted, there may be better resources out there for your case. These are not simple to design.

Comment: I do not want the fractional part truncated. I want it exactly the same. Even if conversion is not possible, I'd be happy if any library can add or subtract two such single precision numbers.